# Implement BidirectionalGridLSTM

Tags: grid, tensorflow, lstm, chatbot, bidirectional

I’m implementing a chatbot using Tensorflow’s seq2seq model[1], feeding it with data from the Ubuntu Dialogue Corpus. I want to compare an RNN using standard LSTM cells with Grid LSTM cells described in Kalchbrenner et al [2].

I’m trying to implement the Grid LSTM cell in the translation model described in section 4.4 [2], but I’m struggling with the bidirectional part.

I have tried using BidirectionalGridLSTMCell, but I’m not sure what they mean by num_frequency_block. They do not mention that in the paper. Does anyone know what they mean by num_frequency_block? In the api docs it says:
`num_frequecy_blocks`: [required] A list of frequency blocks needed to cover the whole input feature splitting defined by `start_freqindex_list` and `end_freqindex_list`.

Further, I have tried to create my own cell. First I do the forward processing with the inputs, then I reverse the inputs, and do the backward processing. But when I concatenate these results, the shape changes. E.g. when I try to run the network with a batch size of 32, then i get this error:
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 32
How can I concatenate the results without changing the shape? Is that even possible?

Does anyone have any other tips, on how I can implement Bidirectional Grid LSTM?

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/
[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01526

Comment: did you ever figure out num_frequency_blocks? I'm running into the same problem, and I can't find a clear answer anywhere online.

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't figured it out..

Answer (score 0):

-tensorflow has bidirectional LSTMs built-in: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/bidirectional_rnn.ipynb

- here's a tutorial for using bidirectional LSTMs for intent matching: https://blog.themusio.com/2016/07/18/musios-intent-classifier-2/

you're missing your second [2] reference link.

is this a helpful baseline, even if they don't provide grids? 
may i ask what you are using it for?

Comment: We tried to use static_bidirectional_rnn/dynamic_bidirectional_rnn, but our input is 2D, and they required 3D. We were not sure how to handle this... We ended up modifying MultiRnnCell and reversed the inputs to the second layer: reversed_inputs = array_ops.reverse(current_input, [True, False]). And I'm trying to implement a chatbot using the translation model from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01526) paper, where they have Grid LSTM cells in a bidirectional network.

Comment: is the chat-bot an end-to-end neural network? or are you using this for something more specific, like intent matching